# Total head scratcher: same page in different language scores differently. Is it me? Is it a bug?

Tags: multilingual

Our website uses an optional language parameter for displaying pages in either English or Spanish, for instance:

https://www.spotmodel.com/product_info.php?products_id=17442&language=en
https://www.spotmodel.com/product_info.php?products_id=17442&language=es

Of course, code is exactly the same, performance is exactly the same, and page generation speed is exactly the same (just selecting different rows for page text locales)

BUT

In PageSpeed, mobile tab, pages with "language=en" consistently score about 10 points LESS than pages with "language=es" (about ninetysomething in "es", about eightysomething in "en").

According to my tests, it happens on every single page (within the bounds of the small score variations). The generated code is exactly the same (except the small text changes), html sizes are also similar or even bigger in the ES version (370k EN vs 377k ES), functions do NOT perform anything differently.

Problem is that, by default, if the parameter is not found, the page served is the English version, hence i'm getting an "orange" score most of the times, instead of the nice "green" on the Spanish pages.

Any clues on what I'm missing? Is it a bug in lighthouse parsing pages with `<html lang=es>`

Comment: Indeed even in the browser (F12, Network) Spanish is better, especially the DOM content. Might there be much more English texts, say in libraries? Or whitespace (compression).

Comment: Already checked, nothing particularly heavy, but anyway loaded libraries are exactly the same too (bootstrap+jquery, nothing more, nothing less). When there's a slight difference, size is usually longer in the Spanish versions than in the English versions :-?